# Get certificate from windows server 2003's CA using C#

Tags: c#, windows-server-2003, x509certificate, certificate-authority

I have a CA in windows server 2003 along with active directory (in the same machine).
Every AD user have its own certificate.
What I want to do is to access the CA to get a certain certificate to cypher data with the public key.

I've been searching but got nowhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you should get Active Directory attribute [userCertificate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677943%28VS.85%29.aspx#ctl00_contentContainer_ctl80) of the user (see [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996408%28EXCHG.65%29.aspx) for example.

If you mean under "to cypher data with the public key" EFS you can use [AddUsersToEncryptedFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363770%28VS.85%29.aspx) (see [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363765%28VS.85%29.aspx)).